# Hortonworks How to download HBase configuration files programatically?

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform

I have a HDP cluster & have java client that needs to download the configuration files (hdfs-site.xml, core-site.xml, hbase-site) at runtime? how do i achieve this? Cloudera Manager provides provide URL way downloading config files, do we have something similar with ambari?

Answer (score 0):

You may use Ambari API or command line utility to download properties and their values set for any configuration file. (But you can download in json format not config file as it is in xml format.)

**API:**

Step1: Find latest config version

```
curl -u admin:admin -H "X-Requested-By: ambari" -X GET  http://<AMBARI_SERVER_HOST>:8080/api/v1/clusters/<CLUSTER_NAME>?fields=Clusters/desired_configs

Sample OUTPUT
{
  "href" : "http://AMBARI_SERVER_HOST:8080/api/v1/clusters/CLUSTER_NAME?fields=Clusters/desired_configs",
  "Clusters" : {
    "cluster_name" : "CLUSTER_NAME",
    "version" : "HDP-2.0.6",
    "desired_configs" : {
      ...
      "mapred-site" : {
        "user" : "admin",
        "tag" : "version1384716039631"
      }
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Step2: Download configuration

```
curl -u admin:admin -H "X-Requested-By: ambari" -X GET "http://<AMBARI_SERVER_HOST>:8080/api/v1/clusters/<CLUSTER_NAME>/configurations?type=mapred-site&tag=version1384716039631"

Sample OUTPUT
{
  "href" : "http://AMBARI_SERVER_HOST:8080/api/v1/clusters/CLUSTER_NAME/configurations?type=mapred-site&tag=version1384716039631",
  "items" : [
    {
      "href" : "http://AMBARI_SERVER_HOST:8080/api/v1/clusters/CLUSTER_NAME/configurations?type=mapred-site&tag=version1384716039631",
      "tag" : "version1384716039631",
      "type" : "mapred-site",
      "Config" : {
        "cluster_name" : "CLUSTER_NAME"
      },
      "properties" : {
      ... THESE ARE THE PROPERTY KEY-VALUE PAIRS ...
      }
    }]
}
```

**USING COMMAND LINE UTILITY**

```
/var/lib/ambari-server/resources/scripts/configs.sh get <ambari host> <cluster name> <config file type>

Example: /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/scripts/configs.sh get localhost Sandbox mapred-site
```

More details are available at following link

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Modify+configurations